# Cannot gain focus on controls

Tags: winforms, tab-ordering

Something stops controls from getting focus with TabKey. The form has a 2 paged XtraTabs, a few group boxes and mostly txtBoxes.

I have set the tab order with the taborder tool. I also tryied it manually.

Something doesnt work.

When I first hit tab, does not even go to the next control (from the tabpage header). Even if I click on a txtbox and press tab, nothing happens.

Any idea on what's wrong with this?

Comment: `XtraTabs` - are you using DevExpress?

Comment: @JensKloster:
Yes I'm using DevExpress. finally solved it. Had to remove a LayoutControl there was from previous editings. It would be nice if I knew how can I have a LayoutControl *and* taborder, but this might be a different thread :p

Comment: :D lol - that was gonna be my guess as well! that darn LayoutControl.. nothing but trouble